# tabulator delete row c#

Tags: c#, tabulator

I am using c# .net core api and tabulator for a small web app

I am having trouble understanding how to delete a row. The documentation has a specific row in the demo associated with the button.

here's the documentation:

http://tabulator.info/examples/4.6?#adddel

the documentation/interactive demo shows just "remove row oli bob"...it does not show the user just clicking on the row and deleting the row...so I'm confused on how to go about an ad hoc delete

My user wants to delete rows ad hoc.

Here's my class file/html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Customers Admin Panel</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.6.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="initTable()">
    <button onclick="loadCustomers()">Refresh Data</button>
    <table id="customers">

    </table>

    <script>
        var table;


        function handleCellUpdated (cell) {
            console.log(cell);
            console.log(cell.getRow());
            console.log(cell.getRow().getData());
            var record = cell.getRow().getData();

            $.ajax({
                url: "api/SalesTrackerCustomers/" + record.id,
                data: JSON.stringify(record),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                type: "PUT",
                success: function(response, textStatus, xhr){
                    console.log("success")
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error){
                    console.log("error")
                }
            });

        }


        function initTable() {

            //Build Tabulator
            table = new Tabulator("#customers", {
                height: "90vh",
                placeholder: "Loading...",
                addRowPos: "bottom",
                columns: [
                    { title: "Customer ID", field: "custId", width: 150, editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Customer Type", field: "custType", width: 130,  editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Customer Name", field: "customerName",  editor: "input" },
                    { title: "Group ID", field: "groupId", editor: "number" }
                ],
                cellEdited: handleCellUpdated
            });

            loadCustomers();
        }



        function loadCustomers(){
            console.log("loading data");
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/SalesTrackerCustomers",
                method: "GET"
            }).done(function (result) {

                table.setData(result);


            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use formatter buttonCross (http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/format) to create delete button. So your code will be like this:

```
{formatter:"buttonCross", align:"center", title:"del", headerSort:false, cellClick:function(e, cell){
  if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?'))
      cell.getRow().delete();
  }
}
```